# META-INF/context.xml causing problems in my Java Webapp

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jndi

I'm deploying a simple Java 7 (I used Maven for project set-up, dependencies, etc) web app  to Tomcat 8 and I have a META-INF/context.xml that I need to specify my database resource:

**project/src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
            username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/javatest"/>
</Context>
```

When I remove this META-INF/context.xml file from the project, I am able to access my jsps but, of course, they return errors since my datasource is missing. However, when I include META-INF/context.xml back to the project, all resources that I try to access give me a 404. Why does it behave this way?

[For reference, I am trying how to use a JNDI data source by following this guide.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example) I did all the steps necessary in that project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any exceptions when the server is starting?

If the jdbc driver is not bundled in WEB-INF/lib and not in CATALINA_BASE/lib then it can't find the class. That would most likely result in a startup failure.

Check catalina.out (if you are on unix) or CATALINA_BASE/logs/localhost/catalina.date.log

**Edit**

Just noticed you have src/main/resources/META-INF

Try src/main/**webapp/META-INF**/context.xml ...

Comment: No, there are no exceptions at all. I think having the context.xml file in my application messes with its path. I also ensured that the Connector/J 3.0.11-stable for Java is in $CATALINA_BASE/lib.

Comment: That seems very strange. I use app.war/META-INF/context.xml files all the time without issue. Are you doing this with just a locally exploded application?

Comment: I basically do a "mvn clean install" to generate my war file. I grab it from the target directory and install it directly to $CATALINA_BASE/webapps.

Comment: That should be about it ... Strange

Comment: @MiguelPortugal I posted an edit to my answer on this last night.If you have an opportunity, please try that. I think and this is a possible bug in Tomcat. Maybe, just maybe, the container is getting confused when it encounters the context.xml at a location deeper than expected and fouls up the deployment of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Do not remove the `META-INF/context.xml` because it is the default configuration for the project! Also do not enter production-password into the default `META-INF/context.xml`!

Use `copyXML="true"` instead! On first deployment to tomcat the `META-INF/context.xml` is copied permanently into `tomcat/conf/Catalina`!

```
Set to true if you want a context XML descriptor embedded inside the application 
(located at /META-INF/context.xml) to be copied to xmlBase when the application is 
deployed. On subsequent starts, the copied context XML descriptor will be used in 
preference to any context XML descriptor embedded inside the application even if the 
descriptor embedded inside the application is more recent. The flag's value defaults to 
false. Note if deployXML is false, this attribute will have no effect.
```

After first deployment update `tomcat/conf/Catalina/webappname.xml` to productive database informations.

Any redeployment will keep using the `tomcat/conf/Catalina/webappname.xml`.